# KeyedProcessFunction with Sliding window

Tags: stream, java-stream, bigdata, apache-flink

Hello Can someone please share example based problem for ("KeyedProcessFunction with Sliding window"). I have to include in my method for checking the number of generation events inside and process them.

Comment: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/learn-flink/event_driven/#example might help you get started. It's an example of a tumbling window, not a sliding window.

Comment: Thank you sir for help.